# Div inside another div does not appear with content property

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put one div inside the other, both have the "content" property in css, but the div inside isn't showing

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_item"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    content: url(urlbox);
}

.box_item{
    content: url(urlboxitem);
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

In my view it seems that the problem is in "content" because with this code below the div appears:

```
.box{
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I wanted it to look like this for example (with content images):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QXTy.png

Comment: You can't put HTML in `content` and urls are reserved for images in that property. Also the `content` property is reserved for **pseudo-elements**.

Comment: It's really unclear what it is you are trying to acheive.

Comment: I use the first div image as a container but with content it looks like it excels over the other elements

Comment: You can't put anything **inside** an image. It seems to me you are looking for an overlay. I suggest you re-think your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using background-image instead of content and position relative in the main div "container" and setting the coordinates with position absolute in the div inside the container I was able to solve:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    background: url(urlbox);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 188px;
    height: 63px;
}

.box_item{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(urlboxitem);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    left: 7px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 49px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want to do but the div is there despite you cannot see. If for example you add a background color to the nested div it will show the current position. I made a demo for you.

```css
.box{
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}

.box_item{
    content: url(urlboxitem);
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="box_item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I want, but in the first div I use an image. I use the first div image as a container